# Replaced my crackset, chain keeps popping off the small chainring under load

Tags: chain, crankset, chainring, drivetrain

Looking for a little lower gearing on my gravel bike, I replaced the crankset with a FSA Omega with 46/30 chainrings, along with a new bottom bracket & chain.

If I stand on the pedals while on the small chainring, I can get the chain to slip & pop off the chainring. This makes starting and climbing pretty rough ;)

The front derailleur looks to be adjusted correctly.

I'm looking for other ideas of what could be causing the chain to pop off, or maybe the FSA Omega crankset is just incompatible with my bike?

Comment: Did you replace the chain?

Comment: chain, chainrings/crankset, & bottom bracket all replaced.

Comment: Check tension (chain length)

Comment: When in the little ring, does the chain clear the front derailleur?  16 tooth difference between the rings is quite large.

Comment: Position of both derailleurs and chain length!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you are on the small or large sprockets in the back?

Comment: @Paparazzi -- chain length seems good.

Comment: @Criggie -- clearance seems good, but could be an issue. I was running 48/34 chainrings previously (14 tooth difference)

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus -- no real difference when on the small/large sprockets in the back

Comment: What rear derailleur and what size cassette?

Comment: Chain angle seems like the most likely problem, though it's also possible that the small ring is simply improperly installed.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus -- Shimano R350 rear derailleur, Shimano XT M771 11-36 cassette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Stupid mistake, here's hoping others will learn from my error!*

When installing the 30T chainring on the FSA Omega crankset, there wasn't an obvious orientation. It looks like I installed it the wrong way.

I re-installed it flipped the other way, and everything seems to be working. Three test rides and no chain drops!

Comment: Excellent spotting - thank you for coming back for closure.  Do please mark this answer as Accepted by clicking the checkbox/tickbox to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a 10sp RD 350 SS short cage (R350 GS seems to be a 9 speed item), you have possibly exceeded the total capacity and are not getting enough chain tension.

Capacity with 48/34 rings was 48 + 36 - 34 - 11 = 39. Capacity with 46/30 rings is increased to 46 + 36 - 30 - 11 = 41. AFAIK, only long cage derailleurs for triple rings have that much capacity.

Do you really need a 30t small ring? Would increasing it to 32t - to decrease the total capacity - be ok for you? Alternatively you could think about replacing the derailleur.

Comment: I suspect you may be correct. The Shimano RD-350 has a spec'd capacity of 37, and was probably squeaking by with 39, but 41 is probably too far off.